# Sticky an animated navbar once scrolled past a certain point

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am trying to sticky an animated navbar to the top of the page once the user scrolls past a certain part. (there are many examples on here, but I couldn't make any work).

I want to add javascript without using bootstrap, without making it conflict with the existing onscroll animation, and without nesting the entire page in that navbar's own div.

Do I use Javascript or is there a method with CSS?

https://jsfiddle.net/p9xfy79x/2/

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};
function myFunction() {
  var navbar = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 85 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    navbar.className = " bar" + " card" + " animate-top" + " white";
  } else {
    navbar.className = navbar.className.replace(" card animate-top white", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Please out line

Comment: The navbar with css "position:sticky" only goes as far as the end of that div container. I need the navbar to go as far down as there is content ie: to the end of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selector `.animate-top` is the one causing the problem here. The main issue is that its setting the inner div of your nav to relative. Just change your css selector to the following and it should fix your issue:

```
.animate-top {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  animation: animatetop 0.4s
}
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/7ze2fukk/

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you sir, for finding the conflict in the CSS! In the end, it turns out that position:sticky still doesn't have support in IE and behaves erratically in other browsers, so I got rid of it and replaced it with position: relative, while adding the change to .animate-top like you suggested. It now seems to be behaving consistently now! Thanks again